# how to solve IronPython error

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I used c# and python by ironpython..

This is my code:

```
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

String URL = "";

try
{
    URL = URLTB.Text.Trim();
    var scope = engine.CreateScope();
    engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("crawling.py").Execute(scope);

    var setUrl = scope.GetVariable<Func<object, object>>("setURL");
    var data = setUrl(URL);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Crawling error : " + ex.Message);
}
```

But I got error:

> 913 is not in required range" at 'Execute(scope)'

I don't know what is 913..

How can I solve it?
Python code is crawling code.. and It works well.

Comment: can  you share full traceback

Comment: @akshat what is traceback..? i just saw in debugging window of VS that _traceback is null

Comment: @SuYeonChoi Can you try to add this line before execute line.            CompiledCode code = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("crawling.py").Compile();

Comment: @AnoopJ I tried to add the line, but I still got the error...

Comment: i think the error is "Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(System.Object)"

Comment: @SuYeonChoi so issue resloved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I searched in other packages imported with the package I initially set and I discovered it's in the HTML python package. It's in the library html and the file is entities.py. The code makes two lists of chars en codepoint. Then it makes a dictionary with the name of the char and set the char. Like this:

```
# maps the Unicode code point to the HTML entity name
codepoint2name = {}

# maps the HTML entity name to the character
# (or a character reference if the character is outside the Latin-1 range)
entitydefs = {}

for (name, codepoint) in name2codepoint.items():
    codepoint2name[codepoint] = name
    entitydefs[name] = chr(codepoint)
```

apparently C# IronPython does not accepts values higher than 255 in the chr(n) of python. 
I "solved" the problem by adding an if in the for:

```
for (name, codepoint) in name2codepoint.items():
    codepoint2name[codepoint] = name
    if(codepoint <= 255):
        entitydefs[name] = chr(codepoint)
```

I don't know if you can really call this a solution but I don't know how to solve it better. I wonder why it does this...